# LCD Horizontal Line with Changing Color : Dead Pixels or Stuck Pixels?

Tags: lcd, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

My monitor recently started showing a black horizontal line yesterday. I tried searching for some solution on the internet and found some good suggestions. Now, recently I noticed that the color of that horizontal line is changing. It was Black yesterday, White in the morning and now in the evening it's kind of Green.

I had tried some methods (but not all) of fixing it but had given up hope and was considering it to be a case of dead pixels. But now that it's changing colors, could it be that these are just stuck pixels and not pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuck/dead pixels are usually individual pixels or in small clusters, and it has to do with faulty film in the LCD panel preventing electrical charge to polarize (twist, or whatever the technology might be used in the display in question) layers that let the light trough.

If it's going edge to edge you most likely have a problem with connection between your panel and underlying electronics. It can mostly be repaired by [reflowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflow_soldering) the flat cable connecting the panel with monitor interface. It will probably surface again within few weeks or months, so it's just a temporary fix unless it's done by hardcore professionals, but it would end up costing more than a new monitor.

Comment: A line means the problem is in the screen's controlling circuitry or connectors.  A dark line is the absence of a signal.  A bright line is the presence of a signal.  If it is a colored line, you need to consider the background.  If the background is light, a colored line could be the absence of a sub-color.  If the background is dark anywhere along the line, a colored line is the presence of a signal.  If the problem is the absence of a signal, it could be the connectors.  If it is the presence of a signal, it is in the circuitry.

Comment: @Enis: Thanks Enis for the insights. But in my case, the monitor is behaving this way even if I disconnect it from my computer. After disconnecting it from computer, when it says "no signal", the line is still visible. So no problem in the connector, I guess.

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks Fixer. The problem does seem to be in the circuitry only.

Comment: @shivams - Enis and I are not referring to the connection between the monitor and the computer.  The monitor contains a sandwich of glass and LCD film, and circuitry that converts the signal from your computer to positional instructions for the film.  There are little ribbon cables that connect the film to that circuitry.  Sometimes they are soldered to the circuitry and sometimes there are little ribbon connectors.  Lack of a signal could be due to either circuitry failure or a bad ribbon cable connection.  The ribbon connection is potentially repairable.

Comment: @fixer1234: Okay. Great. If the ribbon is "potentially repairable", then this is good news. I will look up how it can be done. BTW, would it be preferable to get it done by a professional or can we do it ourselves?

Comment: @shivams - In an earlier comment, you said that you see the lines even if the monitor is disconnected (no background color).  If that's the case, the problem is in the circuitry and there is no cost-effective way to fix that.  If you see the line only where there is bright background, it could potentially be a ribbon cable.  In that case, it takes special tools, knowledge, and proficiency to fix it.  Paying someone else to look at it won't guarantee a repair or long, uneventful service after the repair, and will cost the major portion of a new monitor.

Comment: @fixer1234: When the monitor is disconnected, the lines are visible over the "No signal" message that shows up on the monitor. So, it does have a background color (blue and white).

Comment: @shivams - If it is visible only where there is bright background, it could be a ribbon cable (potentially repairable), or circuitry (not cost-effective to repair except by a refurbisher).

Comment: @shivams What fixer1234 said. You should probably think about a new monitor, and there are discounts just around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

It's less likely, but also possible that there is an issue with the computer-side video hardware.  It should be easy to test which one is the problem if you have either another computer or another monitor.

Comment: Thanks James for the answer. But there is no problem with the video hardware as my other monitor is working fine.